# Inverse sine simplifying problem

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

It's a simple but not popular problem and there isn't a lot to say here, the problem is:

simplify the following function:

\begin{align}
 \arcsin(b\sin(x))
\end{align}

And for example, if b=2 what is the resulting simplified function?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I suspect there's not much you can do, since even $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ cannot be simplified.

Comment: I tried to put b sin(x)=y and solve but I couldn't deduce to anything and I couldn't try a lot.@ NormanContreras

Comment: @Joe You have that $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ when all values are in the appropriate ranges.

Comment: @Allawonder I agree, but my point was that there is no single formula that expresses $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ any more simply without breaking it up into different cases.

Comment: For real values you must have that $b\le 1.$

Comment: The idea of "simplified function" is very imprecise. I doubt very much that for $\,|b|\ne 1\,$ the result can be simplified.

Comment: when I did some searchs I found that $sin(2asin(x))=2x \sqrt{1-x^2}$ @Somos

Comment: @GeorgeNabil Simplifying $\arcsin(2\sin(x))$ is a *very* different question from simplifying $\arcsin(b\sin(x))$.

Comment: @GeorgeNabil Yes, and that does not contradict my previous comment.

Comment: I know but I thought that we can find a solution to this problem when b=2 as we could find for $sin(2asin(x))$ @ٍSomos

Answer (score 1):

Use power series to get the result
$$ \arcsin(b\sin(x)) = (b)\frac{x^1}{1!} +
 (b^3-b)\frac{x^3}{3!} + (9b^5-10b^3+b)\frac{x^5}{5!}
+\cdots. \tag{1} $$
This series converges for certain values of $\,b\,$ and $\,x.\,$
Except for $\,b=\pm 1\,$ the series is very unlikely to be
able to be simplified.

Note  that the (unsigned) polynomial coefficients in equation
$(1)$ are given by
[OEIS sequence A008596](https://oeis.org/A008596).

Note the superficially similar result
$$ \sin(b\arcsin(x)) = (b)\frac{x^1}{1!} +
 (-b^3+b)\frac{x^3}{3!} + (b^5-10b^3+9b)\frac{x^5}{5!}
+\cdots. \tag{2} $$
Here, if $\,b\,$ is an integer, then this **does** simplify.
For example,
$$\sin(2\arcsin(x)) = 2x\sqrt{1-x^2},\;
\sin(3\arcsin(x)) = 3x-4x^3, \dots. \tag{3}$$
This case is closely related to the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the second kind.

Comment: Can you give me a definition for series (1) using sigma notation?

Comment: @GeorgeNabil Thanks for your comment! I added a link to OEIS A008596 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, and I think I should do more work to get a more appropriate expression for me.@Somos

Answer (score 0):

You don't just simplify $\sin^{-1}(b \sin(x))$, unless $|b|<1 $... and even if you only consider $-1<b<1$, I doubt you'll get anything pretty...

Comment: But when I fed this to GeoGebra it gave me real values for b>1

Comment: And if it's not able to be simplified how to write a mathematical expression to prove that?

Comment: if $\sin(x)<p$, you'll get real values as long as $|b|<1/p$...

Comment: well, you might want to try and rewrite $\sin^-1()$ as a complex-valued logarithm and $\sin()$ as a complex-valued exponent, but I doubt you'll get much from it.